# Android theme not applied when calling openContextMenu

Tags: android, material-components-android, android-contextmenu

I have a recyclerview where I want to open the context menu for some items on a single click.  I do this by calling `openContextMenu()`

```
viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> activity.openContextMenu(viewHolder.itemView));
```

I register the view for a context menu using `setOnCreateContextMenuListener` in my `bind` method.

However, the styling on the context menu is different than when it is opened via a long press:
[image: openContextMenu] vs. [image: long press]

The long press version appears to correctly apply the `Theme.MaterialComponents` theme.  Using `View.showContextMenu()` produces the same results as `Activity.openContextMenu()`.  Even `View.performLongClick()` does the same.  The theme is being applied in some way, because when I add elements like `android:itemBackground` to the theme, it applies to both versions of the menu.  I haven't figured out an explanation or fix, but will post here if / when I do.

Comment: How are you appling the Material Desing, have you override android:listViewStyle on styles.xml?

Comment: I'm applying it to the activity in my manifest.  I am not overriding `android:listViewStyle`.

Comment: They are the same style per se, short or long click default material desing is not changiing, https://material.io/components/lists

Comment: Ideally, that would be the case.  However, that is not the behavior that I am experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

The lack of theming of the dialog does seem like a bug, but I now have a better understanding of the cause and a workaround:

The material version of the context menu is designed to pop up from the point where the user clicks on the view.  That information isn't present when calling `View.showContextMenu()`, `Activity.openContextMenu()` or the default version of `View.performLongClick()`.  Using `View.performLongClick(float x, float y)` instead does pass the information, resulting in the material version of the dialog.  Unfortunately, that method is only available on API 24 and up.

A (rather painful) version that behaves as expected for newer versions of Android:

```
GestureDetectorCompat detector = new GestureDetectorCompat(fa, new ClickListener(viewHolder.itemView));
viewHolder.itemView.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> detector.onTouchEvent(event));
```

With a gesture listener:

```
private static class ClickListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
    public View view;

    public ClickListener(View view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent event) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            return view.performLongClick(event.getX(), event.getY());
        }
        return view.performLongClick();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent event) {
        onSingleTapConfirmed(event);
    }
}
```

Seems like there should be a simpler way, so share if you find one!